# install mongodb: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found

Tags: mongodb, libssl

When i was trying to install the latest mongodb-3.4.1 with tar fils, i  encountered the following error:

> libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

then I searched from the net and tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory, created the soft link for the file libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0, but another error occurred like this:

```
   $ bin/mongod --config=mongo.cfg
   bin/mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by bin/mongod)
   bin/mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by bin/mongod)
```

The error was still there even though i reinstalled the libssl1.0.0 by `apt-get install`